# Creating a data frame using pandas from location history data downloaded?

Tags: python, json, pandas, maps

I downloaded the location history json from google maps data and wanted to put all the available content into a pandas dataframe.

```
df['locations'][5] yields the following:

{'timestampMs': '1540084102574',
 'latitudeE7': 327160442,
 'longitudeE7': -1171687098,
 'accuracy': 17,
 'altitude': -13,
 'verticalAccuracy': 3,
 'activity': [{'timestampMs': '1540083982124',
   'activity': [{'type': 'STILL', 'confidence': 100}]}]}
```

I'm able to map the timestampMs, latitude, and longitude with no problem using:

```
df['lat'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['latitudeE7'])/10.**7
df['long'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['longitudeE7'])/10.**7 
df['ts_ms'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['timestampMs']).astype(float)/1000
```

but cannot do that for altitude or vertical accuracy as it returns a "KeyError"

Also within the activity there is a nested structure. How would I map those to the data frame as well?

Comment: What is the exact code that throws the `KeyError`? For the nested structure, look into `json_normalize`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your problem as follows:

```
sample = {
    'timestampMs': '1540084102574',
    'latitudeE7': 327160442,
    'longitudeE7': -1171687098,
    'accuracy': 17,
    'altitude': -13,
    'verticalAccuracy': 3,
    'activity': [{
        'timestampMs': '1540083982124',
        'activity': [{
            'type': 'STILL',
            'confidence': 100
            }]
        }]
}

# Creating an empty `DataFrame` of length one
df = pd.DataFrame([None],columns=['locations'])

# Passing your sample dictionary as its only value
df['locations'][0] = sample
```

Now, both `altitute` and `verticalAccuracy` work fine for me, as these are both `keys` in the outer dictionary.

```
df['altitude'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['altitude'])
df['verticalAccuracy'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['verticalAccuracy'])
```

For the nested items, note that `activity` is a `list` of length one.

```
type(sample.get('activity'))  # returns `list`
len(sample.get('activity'))  # returns 1
```

So you'll need to index the first (in this case, index number zero) item of the list. That item will in turn be a Python `dictionary`, which will need to be accessed through bracket notation or the [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) `.get()` method.

```
df['timestampMs'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['activity'][0].get('timestampMs'))
```

You can apply the sample logic to the *inner* `activity` dictionary key nested inside the outer one.

```
df['type'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['activity'][0].get('activity')[0].get('type'))
df['confidence'] = df['locations'].map(lambda x: x['activity'][0].get('activity')[0].get('confidence'))
```

Comment: dmiytriys! The first portion of the code to pull the altitude and vertical accuracy worked great. By any chance what would I have to look up to get a better understanding of why my initial approach didn't work?